# Log4Net : Error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section

Tags: c#, web-config, log4net

I have a very strange error :

In my web config I have :

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
```

So when I try to connect www.google.com (for example) by my code. I have the error :

```
Error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section
```

if I remove the tmp from my path to have :

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
```

All works fine.

Strange isn't it ?

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: have you verified the tmp folder exists and the web process has rights to write to the folder?

Comment: Of Course, in fact if I change just the name for C:\log4net2.txt, it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I found,

I think it's a bug in IIS.

The problem was I have my website hosted on IIS, in this website, I have an application for my WebServices.

My website and my webservices have their own web.config.

BUT the listener name was the same on the 2 web.config, so when the value was different, i had the problem above.

So to fix it i change the name of the listener :

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener2" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
```

name="textWriterTraceListener2" for the webservice and name="textWriterTraceListener" for the website.

But the better is to separate them on IIS (I will do this later)
Thanks, everybody for your help.